# Reading .txt using ifstream and writing to new .txt file with ofstream, but only first line works

Tags: c++, io, stream

I am trying to read a textfile, `text.txt` with text representing hexadecimal values:

```
0123456789abcdef 
0123456789abcdef
0123456789abcdef
0123456789abcdef
0123456789abcdef
0123456789abcdef
0123456789abcdef
```

I am supposed to read this file and use `ofstream` to write to a new file `output.txt` to write the binary equiavalent of these hexademical values, with `-` representing 0's and `#` representing 1's.

Example:

```
0 = ----
1 = ---#
2 = --#-
...
F = ####
```

And my output for `output.txt` is

```
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
```

when it should be

```
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
---#--#---##-#---#-#-##--####---#--##-#-#-####--##-####-####
```

My logic is there, but it seems that `output.txt` only writes the first line of `text.txt`. This makes me believe that I am only reading the first line.

I am forced to use c-style strings, hence the char array I am reading into.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.txt");

    char words[10001] = {'\0'}; //c-style string
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            myfile >> words; //read myfile text into char words[]

            ofstream outfile;
            outfile.open("output.txt"); //ofstream to output.txt based on character in words[]


            for (char c : words) //the ofstream to output.txt based on char c in words
            {
                if (c == '0')
                    outfile << "---#";
                else if (c == '2')
                    outfile << "--#-";
                else if (c == '3')
                    outfile << "--##";
                else if (c == '4')
                    outfile << "-#--";
                else if (c == '5')
                    outfile << "-#-#";
                else if (c == '6')
                    outfile << "-##-";
                else if (c == '7')
                    outfile << "-###";
                else if (c == '8')
                    outfile << "#---";
                else if (c == '9')
                    outfile << "#--#";
                else if (c == 'a')
                    outfile << "#-#-";
                else if (c == 'b')
                    outfile << "#-##";
                else if (c == 'c')
                    outfile << "##--";
                else if (c == 'd')
                    outfile << "##-#";
                else if (c == 'e')
                    outfile << "###-";
                else if (c == 'f')
                    outfile << "####";
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect it's the `myfile >> words`, but I am not entirely sure. I added a few comments to try and explain the route I went.

Comment: You read all the lines. It just that you for each line you create a new file overwriting the previous one. You should keep your file open instead of closing and overwriting it.

Comment: Why `if (c == '1')` case is omitted? Why not use `switch`? Why not use an array or [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) as lookup table?

Comment: @MikeCat also the representation has a simple rule - so he could make it much simpler with a basic loop.

Comment: @ALX23z thanks so much you're totally correct. not sure how that sneaked past me

Comment: @MikeCAT sadly cannot use any other data structures as we have not learned them

Comment: Your file is line-based, but you are not reading whole lines, just individual words, and you are not writing out any line breaks in the output file.  Change `while (!myfile.eof()) { myfile >> words; ... }` to `while (myfile >> words) { ... }` or even `while (myfile.getline(words, sizeof(words)) ) { ... }`, and add `outfile << "\n";` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, please don't make edits to a question that invalidate existing comments/answers. If you want to add new details, you should add it as an additional edit at the end of the question, not altering the original content. I have rolled back your previous edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used

```
            ofstream outfile;
            outfile.open("output.txt");
```

inside the loop. This makes the file opened in each iteration and this will clear the contents of file. You should move this befoer the `while` loop.

Also note that your condition `while (!myfile.eof())` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). Instead of this, you should move the reading `myfile >> words` to the condition to check if reading is successful before using what is "read".

Comment: thanks so much. i basically instantiate a new ofstream every time i loop and overrides the old one.

just one more quick question if you don't mind: is there a way that I can check when I have reached the end of the line? my output works, but is really long on one line. would using ```getline()``` be the solution here? is that even possible without being able to ```#include <string>```?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this approach for the file handling:

```
ifstream infile("infile.txt");
ofstream outfile("outfile.txt");

if(infile.is_open()){
    while(!infile.eof()){
        //do the readings
    }
}else
{
    cout << "ERROR::FILE NOT SUCCESFULLY OPENED";
}
```

Comment: [`while(!infile.eof())` is bad to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125)